# DateTime non numerical format

Tags: mapreduce, date-format, parquet

I am a beginner in mapreduce and I want to create a job that reads parquet files containing data of a taxi comapny involving the trip-id, pick_up datetime, amount ... the parquet file structure is as follows:

```
.
.
.
    dropoff_datetime = AIpfCdM0AACWgCUA
    dropoff_taxizone_id = 239
    extra = 1.0
    fare_amount = 8.0
    improvement_surcharge = 0.3
    mta_tax = 0.5
    payment_type = "1"
    pickup_datetime = AIrL01s0AACWgCUA
    pickup_taxizone_id = 238
    store_and_fwd_flag = "N"
    tip_amount = 1.95
    tolls_amount = 0.0
    total_amount = 11.75
    trip_distance = 1.4
    trip_type = "yellow"
    vendor_id = "1"
    trip_id = 6863357739012

    .
    .
    .
```

The job aims at counting the total number of trips for each year, however I could not recognize the date format contained in the file. Is there any one who faced such date formats?

Thanks :)

Comment: `Parquet` do not transform date to any specific format, specially like this one. The date time seems encrypted may be because of security reason. Please confirm it within your team.

Comment: @gyan: Thank you for your answer, in fact the date time is in int96 format (found that when I investigated the parquet file schema) so I was looking how to convert it into readable timestamp

Comment: Again the above timestamp data is not `INT96`, as `INT96` is `12 byte signed int` and converting the parquet `INT96` is not difficult, as long as the data is valid.

Comment: @gyan : When I extract the shema of the parquet file with the parquet-tools jar, I have the following:
message spark_schema {
  optional int96 dropoff_datetime;
  optional float dropoff_latitude;
  .
.